# android never calls onCreate of my Application class (registered in the manifest)

Tags: android

I'm experiencing some problem with an Application class I wrote. I simply would like to access it in my activities, but it seems that the application is never instantiated by the android system (thus onCreate is never called either).
My only doubt at this point is if android can instantiate all the applications declared in the manifest or just one.

Here is the code:

```
package org.dyndns.bertuz83.test.applicationTst;

import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application{
private String prova="";

private static MyApplication instance;  

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance= this;

    this.prova="ciao!";
}

public static MyApplication getInstance(){
    return instance;
}

public String getProva(){
    return this.prova;
}
}
```

and the manifest looks like:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:name="org.dyndns.bertuz83.test.applicationTst.MyApplication">
    <activity
        android:name="org.dyndns.bertuz83.test.applicationTst.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<application 
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name="org.dyndns.bertuz83.test.applicationTst.MyApplication"></application>
</manifest>
```

as you can see, the activity I run is declared under another application, but I thought that the second application would have been initialized anyway (in fact, if I add android:name="...MyApplication", my application is initialized correctly)! Am I wrong?

Comment: Why do you declare twice the application? Edit: ok  sorry it is just a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have only one application class and instance.

Btw. you don't need `private static MyApplication instance;`. You can get instance by using `Activity.getApplication()`. If you still need it: you are starting spaghetti code.

Comment: So: if I wanna store some "global" info thanks to a personalized Application class, I simply gotta write and later define it in my <application> tag thanks to the name property. 
And that will be the *ONLY* application instantiated by the system for my app. Right?
Thanks for your piece of suggestion about the singleton, I'll remove it.

Comment: Exactly. I'd also suggest to create a separate model class and instantiate it in Application.onCreate. This way you get a testable object (even if you won't create unit tests for now).